# Replace Last 4 Digits In Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have confidential numbers that I want to replace.
For Example:

```
5712221479
6782236690
```

I want to replace the last four digits by adding 1 digit.

```
5712222580
6782237701
```

So like following:

```
0 becomes 1
1 becomes 2 
2 becomes 3 
3 becomes 4
4 becomes 5
5 becomes 6 
6 becomes 7 
7 becomes 8 
8 becomes 9
9 becomes 0
```

I have this logic for Linux server. But these numbers are in the oracle database. Not sure how to use it there.

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '
NR>0 {                                                      
    for (i=2;i<3;i++) {                                   
        str = substr($i, 1, length($i) - 4)                 
        for (j = length($i) - 3; j <= length($i); j++) {    
            str = str (substr($i, j, 1) + 1) % 10           
        }
        $i = str                                            
    }
}
1'
```

Comment: I think this will be difficult in SQL. You'll need to write a stored procedure that loops over the characters.

Comment: How do you know you updated the secret number? So let's say you do a full update on a table to increase XXXXXabcd by 1 to XXXXXbcde. If more rows appear how do you know how to skip the ones that were already updated and only update new rows? This seems like a very strange (and I say this to be kind...) design.

Comment: I will have a flag in another column that will mark as Y. So the next set won't pick them up.

Comment: Why not just [encrypt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/manually-encrypting-data.html) the data?

Comment: @Barmar You can do it with simple SQL string functions using `SUBSTR` and `TRANSLATE`. There is no need to write PL/SQL or use loops or procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. Here's one:

```
SELECT value old_value,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN (rev_pos >= 4) THEN digit 
                    WHEN  (digit = '9') THEN '0' 
                    ELSE CHR(ASCII(digit)+1) 
               END) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rev_pos DESC) new_value
  FROM (SELECT value,
               LENGTH(value)-x.pos rev_pos,
               SUBSTR(value,x.pos,1) digit               
          FROM (SELECT '6782236690' value FROM dual), -- test value
               (SELECT LEVEL pos FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10) x)
```

Result:

```
OLD_VALUE   NEW_VALUE
6782236690  6782237701
```

This splits the string into individual rows per character/digit using a row generator (the `connect by` piece) combined with substring. Then it uses `CASE` to differentiate between the last 4 digits and the rest of them, and for special wrap-around handling of 9-->0. The others simply move the ASCII value up by one which will move numbers up by one. I used this method to increment just in case you have a non-numeric in there (if you know they are all digits you can simply `TO_NUMBER(digit)+1` instead). Lastly, the modified digits are reassembled into a single string using `LISTAGG` with no delimiter.

Comment: Thanks Paul. This worked fine manually. But when I replaced the "SELECT '6782236690' value FROM dual" with "SELECT column_name value FROM table_name", it gave the following error: 
 [Error] Execution (2: 8): ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: @Sam, You would either need to remove the `value old_value` line at the top or add a `GROUP BY value` at the bottom. `LISTAGG` is an aggregator like `SUM` and if used with an non-aggregated columns requires those non-aggregated columns to be grouped. That column isn't really needed, I just left it in there to see the old vs. the new side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUBSTR` and `TRANSLATE`:

```sql
SELECT value,
       SUBSTR(value, 1, LENGTH(value) - 4)
       || TRANSLATE(SUBSTR(value, -4), '0123456789', '1234567890')
         AS new_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT 5712221479 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 6782236690 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE | NEW_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 5712221479 | 5712222580 |
| 6782236690 | 6782237701 |

Wrap it in `TO_NUMBER` if you want the modified value to be a number and not a string.

```sql
SELECT value,
       TO_NUMBER(
         SUBSTR(value, 1, LENGTH(value) - 4)
         || TRANSLATE(SUBSTR(value, -4), '0123456789', '1234567890')
       ) AS new_value
FROM   table_name;
```

---

For completeness, if you want a method that considers each character then you can use a `LATERAL` join (which is available from Oracle 12) and a row generator:

```sql
SELECT value,
       new_value
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LISTAGG(
                  CASE
                  WHEN LEVEL <= LENGTH(t.value) - 4
                  THEN SUBSTR(t.value, LEVEL, 1)
                  ELSE TO_CHAR(MOD(SUBSTR(t.value, LEVEL, 1) + 1, 10))
                  END
                ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LEVEL) AS new_value
         FROM   dual
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(t.value)
       ) x;
```

Which outputs the same as the previous query and also works for multiple rows. (But don't use it as `LISTAGG` and a row generator will be much, much less efficient than using `SUBSTR` and `TRANSLATE`).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dESMiT8d)

Comment: This worked. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that would be faster and definitely simpler. If you needed to deal with additional characters (like any character on the keyboard) the `TRANSLATE` can get really long and unwieldy. Like I said, there are many ways to do it. Yours are always good suggestions.